# How to determine the cause of windows automatic repair

Tags: windows-10, boot

My Windows 10 device seems to sporadically go into "Preparing Automatic Repair" on boot. I can often get back to a proper boot just by restarting, but then next time I restart the device it does it again.

So I'm trying to diagnose what prompts Windows to begin "Automatic Repair" in the first place? I've been searching and there is plenty of info on how to fix and diagnosing why it might be failing, but very little on why it starts in the first place other than vague speculation. Apparently it may be because of corrupt or missing system files. But how can I check which of the files are corrupt or missing?

The device is running Windows 10 IoT, using write filters. There are a number of exclusions from the write filters but my current working theory is that maybe it has something to do with this, e.g. more (or less) locations need to be excluded here. But to figure this out, I'd need to understand *what* files are corrupted or missing. Is there a log of these checks which would indicate why Windows decided to trigger a startup repair?

I've found `C:\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt` - but this seems more like a log of the checks done by the repair. The "error code"s of all the tests done here are 0x0.

Even a complete list of files checked / other checks could be useful

**Notes:**

- This happens on multiple machines. But with same h/w specs and same Windows image.
- In normal operation the device runs a custom shell application. However I've observed this issue by logging out of the user running the shell application, and logging in as another user which runs "explorer" normally, then rebooting.

**Update**

I ran `sfc /scannow` from the Command Prompt available from Automatic Repair's Trouble Shooting option (write filter still on at this point).

The response was:

> Verification 100% complete.
>
> Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

**Another Update**

This is almost certainly related to the write filters. I performed five consecutive restarts with the write filters off, and the issue did not occur at all. When I turn them back on, it reoccurs on the second reboot after turning them on, and then on alternating reboots after that. (i.e. Automatic Repair's "Restart" option "fixes" it and it reboots correctly. But the next reboot goes into Automatic repair again).

Of course the write filter being on might make it "clean up" some files (or registry entries) on shutdown but not others, which Windows might interpret as "corruption" on the next reboot. But that brings me back to the question: which files / reg keys?

Comment: If you suspect system file corruption you should run the appropriate DISM and SFC commands then provide the resulting logs.

Comment: I have found over time:  1. Improper shutdown (files may or may not be damaged by this); 2. File damage caused by an errant program; 3. Hardware error (often disk errors). These are the things that come up most from what I see.

Comment: @Ramhound - unfortunately I'm not too familiar with DISM and SFC but I'll get reading and find out what I can come up with.

Comment: @John - I think 1 and 3 can be ruled out. This appears to happen even on proper shutdown and across multiple devices / disks. Perhaps there is file damage from an errant program but I'm trying to figure out which file(s)!

Comment: I rarely see that, especially not on multiple machines. Perhaps look for specialized software you have or legacy software that is not fully compliant.

Comment: You should mention this happened on multiple machines

Comment: I did some thinking:  1 startup repair on a Windows 7 machine about a decade ago from running a Memory function in Windows Admin tools. Do not know why. 2 hours or so to repair. 1 startup repair on Windows Insider trying to force it back to non-Insider. Not a good thing to do. Startup repair about 3 hours total back to Insider. So 2 startup repairs in 10 years on two different machines. Message: Startup Repairs should be rare.

Comment: Repair is caused by the system not booting to the logon desktop.